# Extract a str from a variable length link MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dbeaver

I can't find a way to do the following query.

**Given a link:**

```
/trips/oneway/type/2/f/**996**/t/**710**/d/**2020-04-22**/iR/0/l/es/p/1
OR    
/trips/oneway/type/2/f/**8890**/t/**9088**/d/**2020-06-10**/iR/1/c/**2020-06-17**/l/es/p/1
```

I need to extract the str marked in bold:these are= between **f/** and **/t/**,

the codes between **t/** and **/d/**

and between **d/** and **/iR/**.

I can't do it with substring_index() bc the index will vary according the length of the codes..

Can somebody help me please!!??

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these codes are only once in the string, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
substring_index(substring_index(url, 'f/', -1), '/t/', 1)
substring_index(substring_index(url, 't/', -1), '/d/', 1)
substring_index(substring_index(url, 'd/', -1), '/iR/', 1)
```